# Is there a bug with newline character in setPayloadJSON in WSO2 script mediator?

Tags: javascript, json, wso2, escaping, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I've create a simple API like this:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test_newlineScript" context="/test_newlineScript">
   <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/test">
      <inSequence>
         <script language="js">
            var payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();
            mc.setPayloadJSON(payload);
         </script>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

This is just a sample API to show the problem. Actual implementation contains some data mapping.

This code should give me a response equal to the request sent to this API, and it mostly works.

Request `{"test": "abc"}` gives a response like this `{"test": "abc"}`

But request `{"test": "a\nbc"}` gives an error `unterminated string literal`

Of course after getting this error i've tried this request `{"test": "a\\nbc"}` and got `{"test": "a\nbc"}` in response.

Any idea if this is just a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [NashornJS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/Script+Mediator+with+Nashorn+Support) than the default JS Script mediator in WSO2. Given below is a sample of using the NashornJS library in the Script Mediator

```xml
<script language="nashornJs" >
    var payload = mc.getPayloadJSON();
    mc.setPayloadJSON(payload);
</script>
```